# get_header and hook avoid normal call

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I would like to use a custom header, like `get_header('new')`

But I cannot modify the templates easily where the calls are being made due to several reasons. (many files and same code base deployed on several different domains where some domains must not load the new header and use the same templates, so i want to load the new header on one place with a condition based on domain)

Is there any way I could make a hook and call the header function with the parameter myself, but then NOT calling the usual default call?

```
function new_get_header(){
    get_header('new');
    //die or something
}
add_action('get_header', 'new_get_header');
```

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, unfortunately, because `get_header( $name )` doesn't have a filter for the `$name` (it only passes the name with the action call).

However, if you are willing to modify the `header.php` file for each site with something like this right at the beginning of the file:

```
<?php
if ( apply_filters( 'load_custom_header', false ) ) {   
    $custom_header = apply_filters( 'get_custom_header', '' );

    if ( '' != $custom_header ) {       
        // Get the header that we just received
        // and call the native 'get_header' function
        // as usual
        get_header( $custom_header );

        // By calling 'return' we are skipping
        // parsing this template any further        
        return;
    }
}
```

You can then control what header to load like this (you can either place this code in a plugin or in the `functions.php` file):

```
// We are hooking to the 'load_custom_header' filter 
// and return a value of 'true' meaning that we want to 
// load a custom header
add_filter( 'load_custom_header', '__return_true', 99 );

add_filter( 'get_custom_header', function( $header ) {
    // Figure out what header you want
    $some_condition = true;

    if ( $some_condition ) {
        $header = 'new';            
    } 

    return $header;
}, 99 );
```

The obvious advantage is that you don't have to modify all of the `get_header` calls from all of the templates: `single.php`, `page.php` etc. you control all of them in a single place.

Comment: Excellent, it works partly. I cannot add that code to all the header files that are actually being loaded otherwise It will always get to the `return` statement and the header wont load. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sanne You should add the top code **only** to the `header.php` file. I don't understand why would you include that code in your `header-new.php` file for example since it doesn't make sense to go further. The filters would be called again and you would try to re-include the same file. It won't work because you would end up with an infinite recursion if WordPress wouldn't have a default "true" for `require_once` when loading a template. This means you can't include the same header again (through the `get_header` function).

Comment: Yes exactly, thats how I though it works. But can you explain what you are doing exactly with `if ( apply_filters( 'load_custom_header', false ) )` ?

Comment: You need to understand how actions and filters work. Filters manipulate and then return a value. In this case I am returning the value `true` through the `__return_true` WordPress defined function. That value is then evaluated by the `if` statement. Notice that I use `false` as the default filter value meaning that the `if` statement would evaluate to `false` and execution of the corresponding block would be stopped.